# Create windows which I can cycle with Alt-~?

Tags: debian, gnome, window-manager, gnome3

I can make several Firefox windows (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>N</kbd>) and cycle them using <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>~</kbd> (Alt-). Emacs frames behave the same way. I'd like to know how to create windows (system, library, or other calls) which do the same?. My objective (if it's possible for a user) is to arrange the python tkinter Toplevel and Dialog windows act as that. My prolonged search for anything appropriate gave me nothing.

Using Debian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)
Python 3.7
Firefox-ESR 78.15.0esr (32-bit)
GNOME 3.30.1
GNU Emacs 26.1

EDIT

has followed user1686 advice. Minimal ymail.desktop (~/.local/share/applications)

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Terminal=false
Name=ymail
Icon=python
StartupWMClass=ymail
```

/usr/share/icons has many , python too

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter.messagebox import showinfo

if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = tk.Tk(className='ymail')
    mail_client = tk.Toplevel(root, class_='ymail')
    new_message = tk.Toplevel(root, class_='ymail')
    showinfo(title="Cancel sending", parent=new_message, message="""
Send is cancelled due to empty message""")
    root.mainloop()
```

Don't know yet how to change class of showinfo(). xprop WM_CLASS says it is WM_CLASS(STRING) = "__tk__messagebox", "Dialog"

Comment: See also [Alt +Tab behaviour in Gnome](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/80806/62947), note the difference between switching applications (processes) and switching windows.

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/questions/929536/how-to-add-launcher-icon-for-python-script as GNOME Shell "application" grouping is strongly related to mapping windows to app .desktop files (mostly via WM_CLASS).

Comment: className=, class_ = do for Tk, Toplevel. Haven't managed to handle Dialogs (showinfo, etc.,)